# error corrupted file ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to use ImageMagick to convert a CMYK image to a RGB image using the following command:

```
convert inputimage.jpg -colorspace RGB outputimage.jpg
```

If the inputimage is a CMYK image, I get the following error:

```
lcms: Error #12288; Pointer error; probably corrupted file
```

I am using ImageMagick 6.8.8-5 Q16 i686 on Debian.

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243340/imagemagick-convert-cmyk-pdf-to-rgb-jpeg-or-png-and-preseerve-colors