# Extract an image from a PDF in python

Tags: python, image, pdf, extract, pypdf

I'm trying to extract images from a pdf using PyPDF2, but when my code gets it, the image is very different from what it should actually look like, look at the example below:

[image: Text]
But this is how it should really look like:

[image: Text]

Here's the pdf I'm using:

https://www.hbp.com/resources/SAMPLE%20PDF.pdf

Here's my code:

```
pdf_filename = "SAMPLE.pdf"
pdf_file = open(pdf_filename, 'rb')
cond_scan_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
page = cond_scan_reader.getPage(0)

xObject = page['/Resources']['/XObject'].getObject()
i = 0
for obj in xObject:
    # print(xObject[obj])
    if xObject[obj]['/Subtype'] == '/Image':
        if xObject[obj]['/Filter'] == '/DCTDecode':
            data = xObject[obj]._data
            img = open("{}".format(i) + ".jpg", "wb")
            img.write(data)
            img.close()
            i += 1
```

And since I need to keep the image in it's colour mode, I can't just convert it to RBG if it was CMYK because I need that information.
Also, I'm trying to get dpi from images I get from a pdf, is that information always stored in the image?
Thanks in advance

Comment: pypdf has improved image extraction a lot. you might want to give `pypdf` (not `PyPDF2!) another shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [pdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/) to extract the image from your example. 
The image uses *ICCBased* colorspace with the value of *N=4* and *Intent* value of *RelativeColorimetric*. This means that the "closest" PDF colorspace is *DeviceCMYK*.

All you need is to convert the image to RGB and invert the colors.

Here is the code:

```
from pdfreader import SimplePDFViewer
import PIL.ImageOps 

fd = open("SAMPLE PDF.pdf", "rb")
viewer = SimplePDFViewer(fd)

viewer.render()
img = viewer.canvas.images['Im0']

# this displays ICCBased 4 RelativeColorimetric
print(img.ColorSpace[0], img.ColorSpace[1].N, img.Intent)

pil_image = img.to_Pillow()
pil_image = pil_image.convert("RGB")
inverted = PIL.ImageOps.invert(pil_image)


inverted.save("sample.png")
```

Read more on PDF objects: Image [(sec. 8.9.5)](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=206), InlineImage [(sec. 8.9.7)](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=214)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works: you probably need to use another library such as `Pillow`:

Here is an example:

```
    from PIL import Image
    image = Image.open("path_to_image")
    if image.mode == 'CMYK':
        image = image.convert('RGB')
    image.write("path_to_image.jpg")
```

Reference: [Convert from CMYK to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101659/convert-from-cmyk-to-rgb)